# How to fill my recyclerview with adapterdata in my fragment piece?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So I've been searching on internet for a while already now but I just can't seem to find the correct topic to help me out with this.
I have the following code which is relevant for this question:

This is my adapter class.

```java
class SmoelenBoekAdapter(var profiles: Array<Profile>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val layout = layoutInflater.inflate(com.otten.nvvofrankversie.R.layout.recyclerview_smoelenboek, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(layout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val positioner = profiles.get(position)
        var profileImage = positioner.profile_image
        var firstName = positioner.first_name
        var lastName = positioner.last_name
        var plaats = positioner.place
        var adres = positioner.address
        holder.view.naamSmoelenBoek.text = firstName.string + " " + lastName.string
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return profiles.size
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

This is my 'MainActivity' (for this particular fragment)

```java
class SmoelenBoek : ApplicationFragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_smoelenboek, null)
    }

    /*override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        smoelenboekRecyclerView.adapter = SmoelenBoekAdapter(profiles)
    }*/
}
```

xml where adapterinfo has to be filled in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profielPicSmoelenBoek"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/business_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/naamSmoelenBoek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Frank Otten"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/profielPicSmoelenBoek"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profielPicSmoelenBoek"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profielPicSmoelenBoek" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:text=">"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/naamSmoelenBoek" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the fragment where I have a recyclerview in which needs to be filled with the above xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/offer_bg"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchInSmoelenBoek"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        android:hint="Zoek in smoelenboek"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Vind gemakkelijk alle\naangesloten orthodontisten"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchInSmoelenBoek" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:text="Aangesloten orthodontisten"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_title_color"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/smoelenboekRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong or missing here?
I think I still need to set the adapter correctly, but I can't figure that out either...
Hope anyone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SmoelenBoek : ApplicationFragment(){
    var profiles: Array<Profile> = arrayOf()
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_smoelenboek, null)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        SharedInstance.api.getAllUsers {
            profiles = it
            smoelenboekRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            smoelenboekRecyclerView.adapter = SmoelenBoekAdapter(profiles)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the solution to my problem. 
I had to put the layoutmanager and adapter in OnviewCreated AFTER the async call (which I forgot to implement so that was part of the problem first) so the layoutmanager could be set and the adapter could fill my recyclerview with items.
Thanks for the help anyways guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set layout manager for recycler view
smoelenboekRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);
// Set adapter to recycler view
smoelenboekRecyclerView.adapter = SmoelenBoekAdapter(profiles)   


class CustomViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val tvNaamSmolText = view.naamSmoelenBoek
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val positioner = profiles.get(position)
        var profileImage = positioner.profile_image
        var firstName = positioner.first_name
        var lastName = positioner.last_name
        var plaats = positioner.place
        var adres = positioner.address
        holder.tvNaamSmolText.text = firstName.string + " " + lastName.string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class SmoelenBoek : ApplicationFragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_smoelenboek, null)
view.smoelenboekRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);
view.smoelenboekRecyclerView.adapter = SmoelenBoekAdapter(profiles)
return view
    }
    }


}
```